# Translating SDP into SDPA format

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

I'm experimenting with the semi-definite optimisation problem given as Program 5.2 in the paper "[Optimizing Linear Counting QueriesUnder Differential Privacy](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Emcgregor/papers/10-pods.pdf)", which is as follows:

> Given: $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$
>
> Minimize: $u_1 + u_2 + \ldots + u_n$
>
> Subject to: For $i \in [n]$: $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the $n$-dimensional column vector whose $i$th entry is 1 and other entries are 0.
>
> $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{X} & \mathbf{e}_i \\ \mathbf{e}_i^t & u_i \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$;
>
> $(\mathbf{W}^t \mathbf{X} \mathbf{W})_{ii} \leq 1$, $i \in [n]$

I would like to translate this into the standard form used in [SDPLIB](http://euler.nmt.edu/%7Ebrian/sdplib/sdplib.pdf) and the SDPA package, which is:

> $\begin{eqnarray} \min & c^t x \\
> & \sum_{i=1}^m x_i F_i - F_0 & = & X \\
> & X & \succeq & 0 \end{eqnarray}$

Where the matrices $X, F_i$ are $n \times n$ and symmetric. Since $u_i, \mathbf{X}$ are the decision variables in the program, I assume that the first step is setting $x = (u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n, vec(\mathbf{X}))$. From there, I can see how the first constraint(s) of the program can be combined into a block diagonal representation, e.g.

$F_0 = \begin{bmatrix} \begin{matrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{e}_1 \\ \mathbf{e}_1^t & 0 \end{matrix} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots \\
\mathbf{0} & \begin{matrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{e}_2 \\ \mathbf{e}_2^t & 0 \end{matrix} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{bmatrix}$

but I can't quite understand how to express $(\mathbf{W}^t \mathbf{X} \mathbf{W})_{ii} \leq 1$ as part of this. Do I have to expand out $\mathbf{W}^t \mathbf{X} \mathbf{W}$ and work out the coefficients of its diagonal, or is there a simpler way? Can I do something with $I_n - \mathbf{W}^t \mathbf{X} \mathbf{W}$, or possibly even $\mathbf{W}^{-1} - \mathbf{W}^t \mathbf{X}$ if I know that $\mathbf{W}$ is full rank? Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree with all of this?

Comment: Are you sure you want the standard form? Would it be more convenient to express the problem in dual form? That is: $\max \text{tr} \ F_0Y$, subject to $\text{tr} \ F_i Y = c_i$?

Comment: Anyway, $(W^t X W)_{ii} = e_i^t W^t X W e_i = \text{tr} (e_i^t W^t X W e_i) = \text{tr} (X W e_i e_i^T W^t)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard coordinate vector. Would this help?

Comment: In terms of trying to solve example problems using existing libraries, it seems like I need to express the primary problem. It might be interesting to know whether the dual problem offers any insights as well, although I assume that still requires knowing something about how the constraint maps to the standard form right?

Comment: Ok. Got it. Expressing the problem in standard form is definitely doable, just 
a bit cumbersome. I will do it later, unless someone else answers the question. By the way, why not use CVXPY? It gives you more modeling flexibility.

Comment: Mainly because it didn't initially show up when I was looking for SDP solvers. The SDP solvers on [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/) all support SDPA format, so I was using that as my guide (honestly I'd rather use AMPL but it doesn't natively support SDPs).

Comment: The SDPA format is, to my best knowledge, some relic of the past long beyond its use-by date. I would write the model in CVXPY or YALMIP, which give access to all reasonable SDP solvers out there, free and commercial. In YALMIP you write it more or less verbatim, i.e. the three lines of LaTeX you have will be three lines of Matlab code.